# CSS background Image is tiny

Tags: html, css

I'm using some css code to make a bio for a friend but the non-scrolling background is tiny. Maybe 10 pixels in height. Why is this?

(first part works fine)

```
<img rel="nofollow" target="_blank" style="position:fixed; width:100%;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:-2;" src="http://www.texturex.com/albums/Brick-Textures/brick%20texture%20red%20wall%20stock%20photo.jpg">
```

City Picture

```
<ul target="_blank" style="text-align:center;border:4px background-attachment:fixed;background-image:url(http://hdwplan.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/free-hd-city-image.jpg);background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;background-position:0em 0px;margin-left: -10em;margin-right: -10; margin-top:2em; " rel="nofollow">
```

***Here are the bio images***(example)

```
<a href="" target="_blank" style="float:right;margin-right:40px;margin-bottom;5px;border:0px">
<img src="xxxxxxx" ></a>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is done by the float. The `<ul>` is really small because doesn't contain anything, as the images float out. Before closing `</ul>`, try clearing the float, and that should fix it.

`<span style="clear:both;"></span>
</ul>`

[This is what I think from your explanation, you are trying to do, and the resolution to the float problem.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Comment: Hi. You are correct that the image floats are the problem (I deleted the floats to check) but your code does not work to clear them. I put it before the </ul> but the floats do not clear.
Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I think I can only use inline CSS. Where would I add the clear?

Comment: Do you have somewhere <li> tags?

Comment: That could be your problem. Perhaps try adding <li> to wrap <a> tags. If that won't help, try adding <li style="display:none; clear:both;"> at the end instead the <span>. This should clear the float.